# Why does swagger automatically get added to my webapi project?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger

Why am I not given the option to add swagger to an API project? It just gets added and called automatically.

Edit: I am using dotnet to create a new webapi project.

Comment: Probably depends on the environment you work in. This is a detail which you forgot to include.

Comment: if you're using .net 5, swagger is already included on project by default and it is set to initialization page, if you dont want this you can create your project with this command dotnet new webapi -n ExampleApi --no-openapi true